# Decision table to pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

Create a decision table to help the Municipal Bank decide whether or not to loan money to a customer. Include the criteria used by the bank to identify qualified applicants.

```
Conditions                      
Income >=40000? T   T   T   F   F   F  
Credit Score >=600? T   F   F   T   T   F  
Months at job > 12? -   T   F   T   F   -  
Outcomes                        
Approve loan?   Y Y X Y X X
```

Use `pseudo code` to write an algorithm for the decision table created in     question one.

```
If Income >= 4000 And credScore >= 600 And monthJob > 12 Then  
loanApp = Yes
```

I am having trouble converting the table to `pseudo code`, I wanted to know if the partial answer to the second question is on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the approach works, yes. Although if you look carefully, you will see that `monthJob > 12` is not needed for the first column of your condiditions. (there is a '-' there)

A faster approach you can get if you investigate your conditions. We always get `Y` if 2 of the conditions are met, otherwise we get `X`.

So here a optimised version (pseudocode):

```
score = 0
If Income >= 40000 Then
  score = score + 1
Endif
If credScore >= 600 Then
  score = score + 1
Endif
If monthJob > 12 Then
  score = score + 1
Endif

If score >= 2 Then
  loanApp = Yes
Else
  loanApp = No
EndIf
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot